# Appium Ruby Console - Selenium Webdriver - Is there a way to reload code similar to the same command as found in Pry?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am working on Selenium Webdriver automation on an iOS emulator using the Appium Ruby Console (arc). By running `arc toml FILE`, a live emulator opens with a Ruby console. [See arc documentation here](https://github.com/appium/ruby_console). This command also `requires` my `spec_helper`, which also loads my code.

In Selenium-Webdriver automation for browsers, I use `binding.pry` for live debugging, opening a Pry console and using the `reload-code` command to test methods. It's super efficient and I'd love to use this in mobile emulator automation. [See Pry live help docs here](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Live-help).

In the Appium Ruby Console, I'm unable to use Pry live help commands. I *could* use `binding.pry` in my automations and live debug from there, but I have found that to be unstable and prone to crashing after a few minutes.

Is there a way to run a `reload-code` type of command in the Appium Ruby Console? That way, I won't have to tear down and reboot the emulator every time, as it takes a minute or so each time.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this one out. You have to use the `load` command followed by the file path to the file you wish to reload.

`load "../common/helpers/helpers.rb"` reloads the entire helper object while in an arc toml session.

Our spec_helper file is set up to require all objects and helpers, so anytime changes are made it's easy to call `load "../spec_helper.rb"`.

Hope this helps anyone else writing mobile UI automations!